# Let $M=\{v∈V,T(v)=d\}$. Prove that $M=v_1+\operatorname{ker}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation. And let d \in Range(T). Hence, $T(v_1)=d$ for some $v_1 \in V$. Now Let $M= \{v\in V | T(v)=d\}$. Prove that $ M = v_1+ker(T)$. i.e. $M = \{v_1+a | a \in Ker(T)\}$

Solution:

suppose $w \in \{v_1+a | a \in Ker(T)\}$ then $T(w)=T(v_1+a)=T(v_1)+T(a)=d+0=d\in M$. Hence $\{v_1+a | a \in Ker(T)\} \subseteq M$

Now, let $w\in M$, then $T(w)=d\implies T(w)+0 = d$ let $a\in Ker(T)$ , then $T(w)+T(a) = d\implies T(w+a)=d\implies w+a \in \{v_1+a | a \in Ker(T)\}$. Thus $M\subseteq \{v_1+a | a \in Ker(T)\}$. $\therefore M = v_1+Ket(T)$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove $M-v_1=\ker(T)$ by a sequence of simple transformations of the defining expression $M-v_1=\{\,m-v_1\mid m\in M\,\}$ that leads to the definition of $\ker(T)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

In the last paragraph better to take $a=0$, this makes your proof more simpler.